# How use embedded attribute interface in class with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario with an interface attribute in a class and would like to use @Embedded.

```
@Entity
public class Fornecedor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;

    private Numero cnpjOuCpf;
   
   ...
}


public interface Numero {
    String getNumero();
}

public class CNPJ implements Numero {
    private String cnpj;

    public CNPJ(String cnpj) {
        if (cnpj == null || cnpj == "") throw new IllegalArgumentException("CNPJ é obrigatório.");
        if (!cnpj.matches("[0-9]{2}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\/?[0-9]{4}\\-?[0-9]{2}"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CNPJ inválido.");
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNumero() {
        return this.cnpj;
    }
}


public class CPF implements Numero {
    private String cpf;

    public CPF(String cpf) {
        if (cpf == null || cpf == "") throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF é obrigatório.");
        if (!cpf.matches("[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\-?[0-9]{2}"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF inválido.");
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNumero() {
        return this.cpf;
    }
}
```

The expected result at my table **fornecedor**:

**columns:**
id | nome | cnpjOuCpf

How can I do this?

***OBS: I am use Java 8 + JPA 5.4.28.Final for study.***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@Embeddable` the class has to offer an empty constructor. If this is a single attribute class, you could use an attribute converter for this purpose. Anyway, the declared type in the `Fornecedor` class must be the embeddable type `CNPJ`. You can expose it as `Numero` through getters though if you like.